# UWP C++ PrintTask PreviewPage Duplication Error

Tags: c++, printing, uwp, print-preview

I'm currently working on a print task within my app to print a couple of pages to either printer or PDF. I'm using the microsoft printsample as the basis for my code and it all works with the exception of one thing. When I change printers, the printer preview creates duplicate pages of the content I sent to the printer preview.

Here is all my code that handles the printing. Does anyone know what might be causing the print UI to create duplicate preview pages when changing between printers and or print to PDF?  thanks.

```
    void MainPage::Print_Test_Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
    {

        if (isPrinting) {

            pDocument->InvalidatePreview();

            printMan = Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::GetForCurrentView();
            printMan->PrintTaskRequested -= printTaskRequestedEventToken;

            isPrinting = false;
        }


    this->Certificate_SV_1->ScrollToVerticalOffset(0.0);
    this->Certificate_SV_2->ScrollToVerticalOffset(0.0);

    // CREATE THE PRINT DOCUMENT
    pDocument = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument();

    // SAVE DOCUMENT SOURCE
    pDocumentSource = pDocument->DocumentSource;


    // CLEAR CACHE OF PREVIEW PAGES 
    printPreviewPages.clear();

    // Add an event handler which creates preview pages.
    pDocument->Paginate += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PaginateEventHandler(this, &MainPage::CreatePrintPreviewPages);

    // Add an event handler which provides a specified preview page.
    pDocument->GetPreviewPage += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::GetPreviewPageEventHandler(this, &MainPage::GetPrintPreviewPage);

    // Add an event handler which provides all final print pages.
    pDocument->AddPages += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::AddPagesEventHandler(this, &MainPage::AddPrintPages);


    // PRINT MANAGER
    printMan = Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::GetForCurrentView();

    // RAISE NEW PRINT TASK REQUEST
    printTaskRequestedEventToken = printMan->PrintTaskRequested += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager^, Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::PrintTaskRequested);

    // SHOWS THE PRINTER UI
    printMan->ShowPrintUIAsync();

    }
```

.

```
    void MainPage::CreatePrintPreviewPages(Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PaginateEventArgs^ e)
            {

        Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument^ printDocument = safe_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument^>(sender);

        hasOverFlow = false;


        StackPanel^ PrinterPage = ref new StackPanel();

        PrinterPage->Width = 794; PrinterPage->Height = 1123;
        PrinterPage = safe_cast<StackPanel^>(this->Certificate_Page_1);


        // ADD PAGE TO THE COLLECTION
        printPreviewPages.push_back(PrinterPage);

        PrinterPage = safe_cast<StackPanel^>(this->Certificate_Page_2);
        printPreviewPages.push_back(PrinterPage);


        // Report the number of preview pages created
        printDocument->SetPreviewPageCount(printPreviewPages.size(), Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PreviewPageCountType::Final);

    }
```

.

```
    void MainPage::GetPrintPreviewPage(Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::GetPreviewPageEventArgs^ e)
    {
        Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument^ localprintDocument = safe_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument^>(sender);

        localprintDocument->SetPreviewPage(e->PageNumber, printPreviewPages[e->PageNumber - 1]);
    }
```

.

```
    void MainPage::AddPrintPages(Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::AddPagesEventArgs^ e)
    {
        Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument^ printDocument = safe_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Printing::PrintDocument^>(sender);


        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < printPreviewPages.size(); i++) {

            printDocument->AddPage(printPreviewPages[i]);

        }


        // Indicate that all of the print pages have been provided
        printDocument->AddPagesComplete();
    }
```

.

```
    void MainPage::PrintTaskRequested(Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager^ sender, Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs^ e) {


        Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTask^ printTask = e->Request->CreatePrintTask("PRINT TASK", ref new Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskSourceRequestedHandler([=](Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs^ args)
        {
            args->SetSource(pDocumentSource);


        }));


        // Print Task event handler is invoked when the print job is completed.
        printTask->Completed += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTask^, Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs^>([=](Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTask^ sender, Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs^ e)
        {
            // Notify the user when the print operation fails.
            if (e->Completion == Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskCompletion::Failed)
            {
                auto callback = ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([=]()
                {
                    this->DataStreamWindow->Text = "Printing Failed!";

                    pDocument->InvalidatePreview();

                    printMan = Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::GetForCurrentView();
                    printMan->PrintTaskRequested -= printTaskRequestedEventToken;

                    isPrinting = false;
                });

                Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, callback);
            }

            else if (e->Completion == Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskCompletion::Canceled)
            {
                auto callback = ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([=]()
                {
                    this->DataStreamWindow->Text = "Printing Cancelled!";

                    pDocument->InvalidatePreview();

                    printMan = Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::GetForCurrentView();
                    printMan->PrintTaskRequested -= printTaskRequestedEventToken;

                    isPrinting = false;
                });

                Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, callback);
            }


            pDocument->InvalidatePreview();

            printMan = Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::GetForCurrentView();
            printMan->PrintTaskRequested -= printTaskRequestedEventToken;

            isPrinting = false;


        });

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean when you change print way(e.g. the printers or PDF)  in Print view, the printer preview will create duplicate pages(e.g. two pages become four pages) or  the same contents overlap on the same page? And if you use the Microsoft printsample to test, will the same issue occur?

Comment: The situation I can reproduce is: when I switch the direction of printing to landscape or portrait, the duplicate contents will be created(from two pages to four pages). Because when switching the direction, the **CreatePrintPreviewPages()** method will be triggered, the PrinterPage will be pushed again into the printPreviewPages. You can try to add `printPreviewPages.clear();` in the first line of  **CreatePrintPreviewPages()** method to see if solve this issue.